# I am bringing some wood brackets on my luggage. Is that allowed?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

I am bringing some wood brackets on my luggage and have been checking out if there is a problem with that. They are not painted, so I was not sure if I will have trouble going through customs.

Someone knows if there are regulations for bringing untreated wood furniture pieces into Canada?

Comment: you have the dimensions?

Comment: they are 9 by 9 by 3 inches and there are 7 of them

Comment: I think its allowed, I have seen bigger and weirder things onboard but I am not sure about canada..

Comment: Sorry, Are you talking about Customs law? or talking about bringing them on-board and aircraft?

Comment: It could depend both on where you got them and where you're bringing them back to. I believe some nasty critters can infest wooden things of certain kinds coming from certain places which can be a problem when bringing them into Australia ...

Comment: I know this question is a few months old now but I just wanted to add that the problem might not be bringing the brackets in but your intentions on what you're going to do while in Canada. If you don't have the proper visa to show your immigrating to Canada, then the border agents might turn you away (or monitor what you do) for coming to Canada to do business and work.

Answer (score 2):

You may have two problems - are you flying into a US Airport enroute to Canada? I only ask because a lot of international flights do, and then you have to contend with US Customs as well.

However, for Canada, there are certainly some restrictions on plant material, but it could depend on whether it's treated or not, wet or dry, green or not, and what type of plant/wood.

One resource for this is [AIRS - the Automated Import Reference System](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/plants/imports/airs/eng/1300127512994/1300127627409).

> CFIA-AIRS is the automated import reference system of the Canadian
>   Food Inspection Agency (CFIA).
>
> The purpose of the AIRS is to provide accurate and timely information
>   on import requirements. The application uses a question and answer
>   approach to guide the user through a series of questions about the
>   Harmonized System (HS) Codes, origin, destination, end use and
>   miscellaneous qualifiers of the product they wish to import.

Failing that, [Environment Canada lists a bunch of species](http://www.ec.gc.ca/cites/default.asp?lang=En&n=2942DC30-1) and whether or not they're allowed into the country.

If you still aren't sure, and really I'd recommend this anyway, you can contact the [Border Information Service](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/contact/bis-sif-eng.html).

And finally, if in any doubt at all, DECLARE IT.  If it's fine, they'll let you keep it, and if it's not fine, you won't get into trouble as you asked first.